# Phrases with Magento_Quote exceptions are not being translated

Tags: magento2.3

I can't get translations for module Magento_Quotes at frontend[image]:

I try to check invalid coupon code and got untranslated message.

I try to use translates at next locations, but no one are not been translated:

1. Translates exists for the theme (and others works correctly)
2. Translates exists for the module Magento_Quotes
3. Translates added to module's csv file Magento_Quotes

So, if i try the valid coupon code - phrases are translated *correctly*, but Magneto use Magento_SalesRule module for this action.

In debug I determinate that Magento_Quotes throw Exception for invalid coupon codes...

Answer (score 1):

As I conclude Magento has a lot of troubles with JS translation, and more than 3 ways to applying translation.

Most effective, but not covered at all is creating Language Pack

It cover *Magento_Quotes Exception*,

**but not cover:**

modal OK/Cancel

- in comparing inside Personal Area
- in item removing from a cart

---

How to create Language Pack: http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/translation-localization-of-a-magento-2-store/